# Bidirectional communication between model objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I have a question regarding programming concepts rather than a specific question relating to some specific code.

I have two model objects, one relating to Core Data and one relating to Twitter.

They need to interact with each other. The Twitter object might want some tweets from the database, whereas the Core Data object might want to write some tweets into the database.

I could write public methods on each of the classes and have each class call those methods.

However, I feel that this is quite a tight coupling and I want to some other method of communication between the objects.

Would a protocol-delegate system be more appropriate in this scenario?

For example, with the Twitter class declaring a TwitterDataSource protocol and the Core Data class acting as the delegate for that protocol. And vica-versa.

Thanks very much,

Vazzyb

Comment: You might want a controller in between the models to do whatever coordination needs doing, possibly including moving some code form the models to the controller(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, that coupling would be tight. If you would like to loosen the coupling consider using a [Mediator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). As things change you need to only change how the mediator handles the communication between the two objects but not the two individual objects themselves.

[image: UML mediator design pattern]
<sub>(source: [devlake.com](http://www.devlake.com/design-patterns/mediator/mediator.PNG))</sub>

[image: mediator info flow]

Answer (score 1):

> They need to interact with each other. The Twitter object might want some tweets from the database, whereas the Core Data object might want to write some tweets into the database.

Let me stop you right there.  That is a *terrible* design pattern no matter who you are.  Your separation of powers, instead of making your life easier, has created a divide in your project that you now have to remedy by making each object reference each other.  Both of the activities of these objects falls under the concept of a controller, anyhow.  The first can be refactored out into an asynchronous operation, especially if it requires informing the database controller that it's finished.  Instead of considering a delegate, write an NSOperation subclass that writes to the database (serially, of course), and make the database controller mediate both the result of the operation, and the tweets that come in from the other object that get written into the database.  No more mutual references (this is *not* bidirectionality), no more dual-controller objects, no more hassle.